# Nested loop code error free, not executing

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have this code and it doesn't run at all. It is a list of objects, and each object has a two dimensional list in it. It is not executing the code to even display just the flightNo element. I've made a method to display the 2d list in the object, but nothing happens. I tested with a simple print('Hello') at the end and that does work. Can someone tell me what could be wrong here?

EDIT: Full code at: https://onlinegdb.com/HJPqXWXWU

```
elif a == 3:

for i in range(len(FlightList)):
    print(FlightList[i].flightNo)
req = input('Enter flight number to buy tickets: ')
for Flight in FlightList:
    if Flight.flightNo == req:
        for a in range(len(Flight.seats)):
            for b in range(len(Flight.seats[a])):
                print(Flight.seats[a][b], end=" ")
            print()
        qty = int(input('Enter number of tickets'))
        Flight.buyTicket(one, qty)
print("Hello")
```

I have also tried a different method to display flightNo, no execution again:

```
for Flight in FlightList:
    print(Flight.flightNo)
re4 = input('Enter flight number to view seats: ')
for i in FlightList:
    if i.flightNo == re4:
        for a in range(len(i.seats)):
            for b in range(len(i.seats[a])):
                print(i.seats[a][b], end=" ")
            print()
```

Comment: What does "not executing" mean?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq code doesn't run.

Comment: Can you please fix your code indentation and provide `FlightList` and `one` values.

Comment: "@MateenUlhaq code doesn't run." that's as unhelpful as the original statement. Missing items: what's the error, how is it run, is there a self-contained runnable snippet (neither snippet can be run as-is, the first isn't even syntactically valid and the second is missing the `FlightList` data item).

Comment: You specifiy that each object has a 2 dimensional array, you are accessing the data in each object as if it has multiple properties. Please provide some more information about this list or class.

Comment: @SamuelMiddendorp full code can be viewed at https://onlinegdb.com/HJPqXWXWU

Comment: @Alderven full code at https://onlinegdb.com/HJPqXWXWU

Comment: @Masklinn I've edited the post and added link to full code

Comment: Not reproduced for me on your code. What data do you enter to get your error?

Comment: You are overwriting the FlightList at the beginning of your while loop (line 59), so it's always empty when you're executing this branch. Hint: when a `for` loop's body doesn't execute at all, it's because the iterable is empty, quite simply. Note that you could have found this out by yourself by just printing out `FlightList` before the `for` loop...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working code that I modified the location of calling the method and assigning to the variable because every time we have to create a new instance of the class to save data properly and we should not clear the list that's why I changed the position outside of the loop. And this I working properly. for my basic testing. I can improve if you need. and kept your code in the comment's so you can see the change.

```
    import sys
    class Flight:
        def __init__(self):
            self.flightNo = "None"
            self.planeType = "None"
            self.destination = "None"
            self.w = self.h = 0
            self.seats = [["None" for x in range(self.w)] for y in range(self.h)]
            self.depDate = "None"
            self.depTime = "None"
            self.eta = "None"
            self.ticketsSold = 0
            self.pricePerTicket = 0.0

        def displayDetails(self):
            print('Flight No: ', self.flightNo,
                  '\nPlane Type: ', self.planeType,
                  '\nDestination: ', self.destination,
                  '\nDeparture Date: ', self.depDate,
                  '\nDeparture Time: ', self.depTime,
                  '\nETA: ', self.eta,
                  '\nTickets Sold: ', self.ticketsSold,
                  '\nPrice: ', self.pricePerTicket, '\n\n')

        def totalSales(self):
            return print("Total number of tickets sold: ", self.ticketsSold,
                         "\nTotal sales: ", (self.ticketsSold * self.pricePerTicket))

        def buyTicket(self, quantity):
            quantity = int(input("Enter number of tickets required: "))
            cost = quantity * self.pricePerTicket
            for v in range(len(self.seats)):
                for j in range(len(self.seats[v])):
                    if quantity > len(self.seats) * len(self.seats[v]):
                        print("Lessen the number of tickets")
                        break
                    if self.seats[v][j] == "\\__/":
                        self.seats[v][j] = "\\AA/"
                        quantity -= 1
                        if quantity == 0:
                            break
                if quantity == 0:
                    break
            print(quantity, "tickets bought for $", cost,
                  "\nSeats assigned", )
            self.ticketsSold += quantity


    # one = Flight()
    ans = True
    FlightList = []
    while ans:
        print("----------------------------- \n1. Add a flight \n2. Remove a flight \n3. Sell Tickets",
              "\n4. Display seat info \n5. Display total sales for flight \n6. Display flight info",
              "\n7. Display all flight's info \n0. Quit")

        a = int(input("Enter number: "))
        #FlightList = []
        if a == 1:
            one = Flight()
            one.flightNo = input('Enter flight number: ')
            one.planeType = input('Enter plane type: ')
            one.destination = input('Enter destination: ')
            one.w = int(input('Enter number of columns in flight: '))
            one.h = int(input('Enter number of rows in flight: '))
            one.seats = [["\\__/" for x in range(one.w)]
                         for y in range(one.h)]
            one.depDate = input('Enter departure date: ')
            one.depTime = input('Enter departure time: ')
            one.eta = input('Enter ETA: ')
            one.ticketsSold = int(input('Enter number of tickets sold: '))
            one.pricePerTicket = float(input('Price: '))

            FlightList.append(one)

        elif a == 2:
            rem = input('Enter flight number to remove: ')
            for i in FlightList:
                if i.flightNo == rem:
                    del FlightList[FlightList.index(i)]

        elif a == 3:
            for i in range(len(FlightList)):
                print(FlightList[i].flightNo)
            req = input('Enter flight number to buy tickets: ')
            for Flight in FlightList:
                if Flight.flightNo == req:
                    for a in range(len(Flight.seats)):
                        for b in range(len(Flight.seats[a])):
                            print(Flight.seats[a][b], end=" ")
                        print()
                    qty = int(input('Enter number of tickets'))
                    Flight.buyTicket(one, qty)
            print("Hello")

        elif a == 4:
            for Flight in FlightList:
                print(Flight.flightNo)
            re4 = input('Enter flight number to view seats: ')
            for i in FlightList:
                if i.flightNo == re4:
                    for a in range(len(i.seats)):
                        for b in range(len(i.seats[a])):
                            print(i.seats[a][b], end=" ")
                        print()

        elif a == 5:
            re4 = input('Enter flight number to view seats: ')
            for i in FlightList:
                if i.flightNo == re4:
                    i.totalSales()

        elif a == 6:
            re4 = input('Enter flight number to view seats: ')
            for i in FlightList:
                if i.flightNo == re4:
                    i.displayDetails()

        elif a == 7:
            for item in FlightList:
                item.displayDetails()

        elif a == 0:
            sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Thank you, it does work now. As you mentioned you can improve it, can you give some more suggestions. I'm new to Python

Comment: sure...    it is the correct answer right or you are expecting anything more sophisticated..please let me know..

Comment: yes, it does work so it is the right answer. However, if you have some advanced solution, I'd be happy to know.